# When writing an answer, can we be notified if people are voting to close/flagging the question?

Tags: feature-request, support, answers, vote-to-close, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add an alert when answering a question that has at least a close vote as duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40316/add-an-alert-when-answering-a-question-that-has-at-least-a-close-vote-as-duplica)

I was writing a detailed answer to a question. Before I could post it (when it was just about done), the question was closed. So either we need notifications that people are voting to close/flagging for moderator review (my preferred solution) or be able to post answers if we already have an answer written when the question is closed. It's just annoying to spend 3-5 minutes writing an answer only to have the question closed before you can post.

Comment: There is some sort of a window between when the question is closed and when you can no longer post answers. It's pretty small, though.

Comment: Why are you answering a question that needs to be closed?  If it's closed as a dupe you can adapt your answer for the dupe, if it's being closed for another reason you shouldn't encourage the behavior.

Comment: @KevinVermeer I don't think it should have been closed, so I promptly voted to re-open. But still, the fact that I kept writing as people were voting to close prevented me from seeing what people were voting and the comment discussion as to the question's state. If it doesn't get reopened, I wasted 5 minutes writing an answer to it.

Comment: @KevinVermeer Really, what is helpful is a way to know that people are saying that it should be closed so I can stop writing my answer (it gets saved, so it's OK), refresh the comments and votes to see how people are voting, and try to improve the question/add a comment to reach a decision.

Comment: @Kate I think that's a different issue. This is about close votes being cast while he is already busy writing an answer.

Comment: @CodeInChaos is right. This is suggesting an active notification of flags/votes to close, just like you have active notifications of new answers.